# ASP.Net progress on first page load

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updateprogress

I am working on ASP.Net project and Ajax (`UpdatePanels` and `UpdateProgess`)

Everything works fine. When I click on a button in order to refresh a drop down list for example, I see progress image in `UpdateProgress` control.

But, what I have a problem for the first page loading:

I need to display the page content quickly and then feed all dropdowns from database with a progress image animation.

It is hard to do because the first page loading is slow because everything is done in page load.

Anyone have a solution to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't much you can do about first page load, because your code has not yet been compiled to be able to run, and show your progress dialog yet.  It's a catch-22.

The best you can do is use a warmup tool to try and keep the app domain loaded.